# Cannot record requests because of Certificate Errors

Tags: jmeter

lately I changed my PCs and right now I am using M1 MacBook Pro and Lenovo ThinkPad (Windows). On Firefox, I configured my proxy and certificate setting just as I did with my previous computers. But when I try to record the traffic of targeted websites, I receive different certificate and SSL errors. I see the requests on View Results Tree and Recording Controller, but i get the following errors:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:370)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:313)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1463)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:414)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:819)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$200(SSLSocketImpl.java:75)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:902)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.HttpRequestHdr.parse(HttpRequestHdr.java:138)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:202)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.security.ssl.HKDF.extract(HKDF.java:93)
    at sun.security.ssl.HKDF.extract(HKDF.java:119)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHello.setUpPskKD(ServerHello.java:1147)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHello.access$900(ServerHello.java:53)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$T13ServerHelloProducer.produce(ServerHello.java:547)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:420)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.goServerHello(ClientHello.java:1096)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:1032)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(ClientHello.java:716)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(ClientHello.java:683)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:376)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:479)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:457)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:200)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1290)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:401)
    ... 7 more
```

---

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Session has no PSK
at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.PreSharedKeyExtension.checkBinder(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.PreSharedKeyExtension.access$1100(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.PreSharedKeyExtension$CHPreSharedKeyUpdate.consume(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLExtension.consumeOnTrade(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLExtensions.consumeOnTrade(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHello$T13ServerHelloProducer.produce(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.goServerHello(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$T13ClientHelloConsumer.consume(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.onClientHello(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHello$ClientHelloConsumer.consume(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$200(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.HttpRequestHdr.parse(HttpRequestHdr.java:138)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:202)
```

---

```
org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:187)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:843)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:574)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1231)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:237)
Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: The server failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:149)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
... 6 more
```

And on Sampler Result tab it shows me this warning:

**ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter Proxy certificate**

---

And how I configured Mozilla Firefox and JMeter:

- Added localhost with 8888 port as my proxy
- Added Jmeter Proxy certificate into my certificates
- Made sure that JMeter is set to 8888 port.

---

Waiting for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration seems valid to me so I can only think of possible bug in Java runtime like [JDK-8213202](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213202)

So you might want to try i.e. [Azul Zulu Builds of OpenJDK](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?os=macos&architecture=arm-64-bit&package=jdk) for `arm-64` and see whether it resolves your issue.

Alternatively you can consider using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates